# I’m trying to find out why ‘Rendered image’ is different than what I see in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[image]

I like viewport image, looks like glass, but in rendered image looks like marble, low reflections, low colors and much more red color instead of green.
How can I obtain redered image same as the image in Viewport?

[image: Outliner]

Here is Blend file.

Download HDR image from

https://polyhaven.com/a/ninomaru_teien

and use *sphere.0003_with_HDRI*
for texture in ImageTexure node

[image]

Comment: Hello, first thing look into your Outliner, it looks like you've hidden something in preview but not in render. If it's still not your problem, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have just one light source, a big sphere with HDR image, as texture. The camera is inside the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

What you show in your first screenshot is the *Material* preview, it is not accurate, for example it won't reflect the other objects, also some material don't work fine, but if you switch to *Rendered* preview it seems to match the final render:

[image]

Comment: But I like image in "material preview" 

It looks like a glass shader. Render Image looks like marble shader. How can I obtain that glass effect?
 
How can I render that image?

Comment: In that case you need to change the material, or you can render the 3D viewport as it is: On the top of the 3D View > View > Viewport Render Image

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution. SOLVED!